# Problem with merging resources with gradle when working with multiple projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have two projects

**Parent** project A and **child** project B. Meaning that in project A i have:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':B')
```

Project B (pkg: com.something.b) has one service and some tests, that depends on it's own resources found in src/main/resources. (Tests on this project work fine because resources are ok)

Project A (pkg: com.something.a):
Needs to @Autowire service from B, so it has @ComponentScan(com.something). 
When it needs to run tests, these are failing because resources from Project B are missing.

To me it seems like when building "project A" spring finds on its classpath test beans from project B and tries to initiate them. That test tries to load file from resource folder, but trouble is resources from project B are not in Project A. Build (test) is failing

Let me try rephrase question. How can i run tests in both projects, and share same resources? Or is there any other more elegant way to do it?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The elegant way to do what you want is creating a common library to share to any service that you see it necessary.

[common library multi module](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/)